# SCCM Client Activity Report Issue

Tags: server, windows-server, sccm

We have a computer that may have been stolen and am trying to find the activity on the System Center Configuration Manager. I was able to see who the last person logged in was, but there are other dates showing but not sure what they are representing.

Here are my questions: When looking at the Client Activity Details under "Assets and Compliance," it's showing a "Policy Request" as 9/27/2017.

1. Is the policy request originating from the SCCM server or the client?
2. Does the client computer have to be actively connected to the network in order to process the request?

[Screenshot from Configuration Console Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PqCm.jpg)

Thank you for any assistance, please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: I think you should ask this on https://superuser.com/. This site is about programming questions and as such this question is off topic on here.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and posted that there.